# Competition among processes for resources

Tags: concurrency, process, operating-system

My OS textbook says the following in a chapter discussing concurrency:

> Concurrent processes come into conflict with each other when they are competing for the use of the same resource. In its pure form, we can describe the situation as follows. Two or more processes need to access a resource during the course of their execution. Each process is unaware of the existence of other processes, and each is to be unaffected by the execution of the other processes. It follows from this that each process should leave the state of any resource that it uses unaffected.

My question specifically concerns the last sentence:

> It follows from this that each process should leave the state of any resource that it uses unaffected.

This does not make sense to me. If a process is using a resource, then it must necessarily affect the state of that resource. This seems obvious, but it sounds like the sentence is disagrees?

I would greatly appreciate it if the members of this site could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Very poor english. I see why it doesn't make any sense. And they probably charged you $150 for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not clear to me in what context this was said, as you mentioned a small portion of the quote. And didn't even bother to mention the book you quoted. However, I can shoot in the dark and assume that what they meant is: A process using resource `X` should, once done using it, leave it unaffected. That is, if `processY` decides to use logical resource, i.e. a `file`, it should not write or change the file as this might affect `processZ` which needs to use the file with its original data.

When it comes to physical resources, the statement above makes no sense... unless you provide the full quote.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The quoted passage comes under the same title as that of this question: "Competition among processes for resources". It mentioned I/O devices, memory, processor time, and the clock as examples. I apologise for leaving that part out. Does that help?

Comment: @handler'shandle
How can a process affect the state of a resource ? As far as I know the state of a resource is being used or idle. I can't answer your question properly then.

Comment: I can try though: two process in a system competing for CPU time. The state of the registers should be saved when a process preempts the running process. So that they can be restored whenever the process gets to run again. 
I can't really think of a better example.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Indeed, It seems that it is referring to physical resources, which is why I thought it makes no sense. If it was discussing logical/virtual resources, then that would make sense, as you have already said.

Comment: @handler's handle try reading my second comment about CPU usage.

Comment: I read it. I think your comments are correct, and the passage is just written badly. Even the CPU example seems contrived and not completely compatible with what the book is describing. As you first described, it seems that what the book is referring to has to do with virtual/logical resources, would you agree?

Comment: I just read (later in the textbook) about mutual exclusion. I think it is referring to logical/virtual resources with implicit reference to mutual exclusion. I'll accept your answer, since I suspect it is discussing the correct context. Thank you again for the assistance.